# Where clause error : column does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, variables, where-clause, psql

I have a variable called 'name' and it stores a different strings every time. 
However, I found that I cannot put the variable 'name' in the WHERE condition.

It will have "column "name" does not exist" error if I run the code below.

```
curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = name ")
```

What's your suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: You missed the quotes. It should be `hisname = 'name'`. Try `curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = '{0}'".format(name))`

Comment: no  if I added the quotes it will be literally the string "name" @mshsayem

Comment: name is a variable that has string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = %s", (name,))
```

Comment: Why we have to add , ?

Comment: You need to pass a `tuple` variable. Plain braces are treated as an expression and passed as a normal variable. The comma at the end tells the python interpreter that it is a tuple.

Comment: Do I always have to pass a tuple variable in the WHERE clause?

Comment: If you want to execute parameterized query and the parameters auto-escaped (which is always desired) you should do it this way. But you can pass plain query too. Like this: `curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = '%s'"%name)`. But it is risky as it is prone to sql injection.

Comment: I see. Learned a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = %s", (name,))

(Edited to make the second argument a tuple.)

Comment: What does % mean?

Comment: Is there any other ways to do it beside this?

Comment: The "%s" means you want to put a string there in the query and, since it is the first "%" variable in your query, that the next argument to curs.execute will be the string for that spot.

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Is name a string?

Comment: Yep  I just tried 'print(type(name))', it shows that '<class 'str'>'

Comment: Can you try curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = %s", (name))

Comment: Just tried to add a () around name, still the same. It says  
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: I tried (name,) and it works. But still thanks you a lot !

Comment: Apologies. I have now fixed the tuple syntax in my answer. Very sloppy on my part and @mshsayem posted the correct syntax first.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to check if the value of hisname is name so for doing this name should had been string the format would be:
curs.execute("SELECT id FROM school WHERE hisname = %s", (name,))
This makes name a string